# How to detect flash content using selenium-wedriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating a web site; entire website is in html except few 'Copy' buttons are in flash. As there is no element for that button, I couldn't verify it's functionality (I have to check whether it's clickable & clicking on it results into coping contents in clipboard). Is there any way, we can automate that button's functionality by adding java script snippet or something?
I'm using ruby api's for automating the site.

Comment: We need a whole lot more information about how you're generating the HTML, i.e., the views and/or HTML templates. As is, you're asking us to reach into a magic hat and come up with a solution that fits your unique situation, and we can't do that.